# PHP output not sliceable by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following array in Javascript and it works perfectly when I use the slice command to access variables

```
dataSequence = [
    {
        name: 'Week 1',
        data: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,5]
    }, {
        name: 'Week 2',
        data: [6, 12, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2,6]
    }
    ];
```

Then when I use this PHP script via Ajax to show the same data.

```
$out = "[
    {
        name: 'Week 1',
        data: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,5]
    }, {
        name: 'Week 2',
        data: [6, 12, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2,6]
    }
    ]";
 echo $out;
```

here is my Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
url: "gettimedata1.php",
type: 'POST',
}).done(function(msg) {
dataSequence = msg;
data = dataSequence[0].data.slice();
});
```

It throws the message "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined".

What do I need to do to format the PHP output correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Use arrays and `json_encode()` to output that json. Any error in your DevTools/console?

Comment: Also unless you are sending a json content-type header as a response on the server jQuery won't auto detect it as json and parse it for you, you would need to do it manually or set `dataType` to json so jQuery knows to parse it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the correct way to output json from PHP

```
$a = array(
        array('name' => 'week1', 'data' => [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5]),
        array('name' => 'week2', 'data' => [6, 12, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 6])
);
$json = json_encode($a);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

You should then be able to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "gettimedata1.php",
  type: 'POST'
}).done(function(response) {
  data = response[0].data.slice();
});
```

You may have to fiddle with the PHP a little I do not have a PHP environment to test on and its been a few years since I last coded in it.

Comment: No, that is not the correct way, because `$obj = {{ name: ...` is not even valid PHP to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe You are right, been too many years away from PHP... will update